# MediaPlayer State Listing

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing an app in which I'm streaming remote videos.
But I am confused with the states of [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) states.

Can anyone please list out all the states of [Android MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) with its value?

Thanks in advance!